# Mysql preventing truncate and drop table statements for a specific table

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a MySQL table that serves as an immutable event store. I added triggers to prevent rows from being updated or deleted;

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  str VARCHAR(32),
  ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
);


CREATE TRIGGER stop_update BEFORE UPDATE ON t2
FOR EACH ROW
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'UPDATE not allowed!';

CREATE TRIGGER stop_delete BEFORE DELETE ON t2
FOR EACH ROW
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45007' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE not allowed!';
```

That part works fine.
But I am unable to prevent the TRUNCATE TABLE or DROP TABLE statements on that specific table.

MySQL doesn't support DDL triggers. Currently I have revoked the drop and truncate permissions for the web app user.

But I would like to add some sort of warning/notice/tripple confirmation dialog thing for the root user as well, just in case someone down the lane accidentally/mistakenly/intentionally tries to clear/drop the table.

Is it possible to add some kind of stored procedure [or anything] in MySql that can prevent a drop/truncate on a specific table? Or at least can warn that this is a special table and should not be removed or cleared.

Comment: You can move ALL logic of working with this table and its data into stored procedures (with definer of root or another login, and sql security as definer) and revoke all rights to that table from web app users at all (or grant SELECT only, for example). None operation absent in SP can be performed. And triggers will not be needed too. And no admin notice needed - no way to delete data.

Comment: Be cautious about `REVOKE` -- If it was not explicitly `GRANTed`, I think `REVOKE` silently ignores you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting things like that is a separate database.  Then `GRANT` users access to their database(s) with 'full' permissions (or whatever) and `GRANT` very limited access to this db:

```
GRANT SELECT ON Specialdb.* TO ...
```

If you find you need to let them do something less safe, create a Stored Procedure with security=Definer.  The definer could be `root` and you can do whatever you want.  However, since you control the proc, you control what things they are allowed to do.